# Edit NSUserDefaults Managed Configuration Dictionary

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

MDM Providers write to a dictionary which is retrievable using

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.DictionaryForKey("com.apple.configuration.managed")
```

How can I programatically write key/value pairs to this dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly retrieve the configuration dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary configDic = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.DictionaryForKey("com.apple.configuration.managed").MutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary;
```

Then you can modify this `NSMutableDictionary` like:

```
configDic["key1"] = (NSString)"value1";
```

At last write back to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(configDic, (NSString)"com.apple.configuration.managed");
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
```

Because `NSDictionary` can't be modified after initialization, we need to convert it to `NSMutableDictionary`. If the value of `configDic` is type of `NSDictionary`(or `NSArray`), we also need to copy it deeply before we want to modify it.